# Why does readimage and writeimage takes a lot of time for PNG images in imagemagick?

Tags: go, imagemagick

I'm using Imagemagick version 7.0.5-4 to perform image processing operations like crop, resize etc with [go-graphics](https://github.com/gographics/imagick) library. I also manage a pool of magickwand objects.

```
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png tiff xml zlib
```

The read time of image to MagickWand object as `magickWand.ReadImage(<url>)` in png images is very high compared that of jpg images. For images of size around 22kb, reading a jpg file takes around 300ms and that of png image takes around 1-2 minutes.

Edited:

When a single request is sent to server, the read operation takes around 20ms, but when on load of 100rps, it goes till 2-4 minutes. This trend is only in png images, not in jpg.

Any ideas on what can be done different in reading png files and how it can be made performant? Its fine to reduce the quality of images to around 60%. Tried options like `SetImageDepth` but it made no difference.

Comment: There's too much information missing for a sensible answer. Are you running an ancient version? Are you running on a Raspberry Pi Zero? What image are you using?

Comment: PNG compression takes more time than JPG compression. Please post your input image and we can time test conversion for you. Perhaps your Imagemagick version is old or your libpng is old.

Comment: Unlike JPEG compression, PNG compression performance is very dependent on the quality setting in a non-linear way, and image contents so it would also help to see your actual code and actual image.

Comment: PNG compression is more computationally intensive than JPG compression. But it would pay to check your libpng delegate and update if not current.

Comment: The version of ImageMagick  we are using is 7.0.5-4 and we are running on a UBUNTU box of version 16.04. Every time we get a request we download it in to the disk and read from it and we delete the image. This reading takes less time for jpgs when it is 100 rps but this reading time increases eventually for pngs when the requests rate is more than 20 rps!!

Comment: JPG images are 8-bits and are smaller in file size than the equivalent 24-bit PNG images. So upload or reading the PNGs will take longer and use more resources.

Comment: So does it mean even though both jpeg and PNG images are of same file size, PNG images take more resources than JPEG? What do you mean when you say about resources?

Comment: I have also observed that read time of PNGs is increased only because write time is increased  i.e, first write time is increased because of which read time is increased!

Answer (score 2):

The compression quality parameter has a different effect and meaning when dealing with PNG files from when dealing with JPEG files.

PNG compression is **always lossless** and the appearance is **never affected** by the quality. As I cannot see your images, I would suggest you either don't bother compressing since it will happen anyway, or that you use a quality of 75. If you tell me you are saving cartoons or line drawings, I might advise differently.

Please have a read [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) and do some experiments yourself with the tradeoff between time and filesize.

I have made you some plots to show the effect on time to compress and  compressed size for different quality settings using two different kinds of images - cartoons and photos - so you can see the effect.

Here is a cartoon:

[image]

Look at how the quality setting (0-100) affects time and size with JPEG output:

[image]

Now look what happens if you use those same quality settings (0-100) when generating PNG output:

[image]

---

Now let's look at compressing an iPhone photo to JPEG:

[image]

And when compressing an iPhone photo to a PNG:

[image]

---

Hopefully you can see that using one quality setting from your config file for both PNG and JPEG and with photos and cartoons/line drawings is not ideal.

Comment: The problem is not with the compression but with the reading and writing!! I have given more information above.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some graphs - hopefully you can see that the quality setting has a significant influence on write time and size - and also in a different way with different types of images.

Comment: This might not help but can get you some good understanding on the behaviors of JPEG vs PNG